# Is it possible to import a class defined inside a function?

Tags: python, pyramid, python-import

There is a class from a 3rd party system that I'd like to sub-class for my own purposes, but it's defined within a function, like so:

```
def foo():
    class Bar():

    return Bar
```

If I try to import it just with `from x import bar`, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Bar'`.  Is it possible (or wise) to import Bar?  Perhaps the original coder put the class inside the function specifically to prevent others from using it directly?

The class I'm trying to get is CookieSession, defined inside BaseCookieSessionFactory, which can be found here:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/_modules/pyramid/session.html

It already does 90% of what I want, and it seems like it would be a waste to implement my own from scratch, since I would just be copy-pasting much of the code.

**Edit:**
Following the advice in Chepner's answer, I sub-classed it by building my own factory function:

```
from pyramid.session import SignedCookieSessionFactory

def MySessionFactory(secret, [other args here...]):
    @implementer(ISession)
    class MySession(SignedCookieSessionFactory(secret)):
       ...
    return MySession
```

Comment: You would need to import the function `foo` and then call it `c = foo()` to get the class `c`. Is there any reason why doing so would not work with what you are attempting to do?

Comment: There is not a single class `Bar`. Rather, each time you call `foo()`, a *new class* named `Bar` is created, and a reference to it returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't import it, because it doesn't exist until `foo` is actually *called*. However, it appears that `foo` simply defines the function and returns a reference to it. In that case, you just need something like

```
from otherfile import foo
Bar = foo()

x = Bar()  # create an instance of Bar
```

Comment: In that case, is it somehow possible to sub-class Bar?  Writing class MyBar(foo()): seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @NateAllen - Do what chepner said and then do `class MyBar(Bar):`.  That is about as clean as you can get.

Comment: Also, note that the whole point of a factory function is to be called to return references to classes. Doing this is exactly what you are *meant* to do with `BaseCookieSessionFactory`. It's possible that you don't need to subclass the return value at all; if you pass the appropriate values to the function, you may be able to use the returned class as-is.